# Android avoid soft keyboard when startup

Tags: android-layout, android-softkeyboard

Below is a layout displaying a EditText at the top and a listview below it.
when the layout starts, the EditText will be in focus and the keyboard is open by default.
how can i avoid opening the keyboard until i touch the EditText intending to start typing?
thank you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/White"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="@string/title"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:hint="@string/Search"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/Gray" 
        />

    <ListView
        android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
         />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_add"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/Add"
        android:onClick="onAdd"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would help . Just add a line in your manifest

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.example.activity"

        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" // Add this to your manifest
        android:label="@string/something">
    </activity>
```

Comment: it works, i didn't realize that this goes to the manifest. thank you